# Finding the word with maximal length from RDD in SPARK

Tags: python, function, apache-spark, rdd, databricks

Working in SPARK Databricks I want to find the word of biggest length from the RDD **wordRDD**.

I have created a function in Python:

```
def compare_strings_len(x, y):
if len(x) > len(y):
    print(x)
elif len(x) < len(y):
    print('String 2 is longer: ', y)
else:
    print(min(x,y))
```

and I want to insert this function inside **reduce** with the code below:

```
    word_length = (
    wordRDD
    .map(lambda x : (x, 1))
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y : compare_strings_len)
)
print(word_length)
```

The result I get is:

```
PythonRDD[151] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:58
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems here:

- reduce function need to return back the actual value, not just print result.  It should be something like this:

```
def compare_strings_len(x, y):
  if len(x) > len(y):
    return x

  return y
```

- instead of `reduceByKey`, the `reduce` function should be used
- you need to get result from RDD after performing reduce, like: `word_length[0]`

P.S. Frankly speaking, I would use Spark SQL instead of that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Already solved:

```
wordRDD.reduce(compare_strings_len)
```